# 3 channel depth image 1 channel

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, kinect

I have record a depth video using Kinect v2, when I extracted images using MATLAB then each [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5j8xsmnhuuye49m/image2.png?dl=0) is 3 channel. Normally the images I saw are just 1 channel. Please any one tell me how can make this 3 channel image to 1 channel?

Here is the code of the depth part:

```
IplImage depth = new IplImage(512, 424, BitDepth.U16, 1);
CvVideoWriter DepthWriter;
Width = sensor.DepthFrameSource.FrameDescription.Width;
DHeight = sensor.DepthFrameSource.FrameDescription.Height;
WbDepth = new WriteableBitmap(DWidth, DHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Gray16, null);
int depthshft = (int)SliderDepth.Value;
using (DepthFrame depthframe = frame.DepthFrameReference.AcquireFrame())
ushort* depthdata = (ushort*)depth.ImageData;
if (depthframe != null)
   {
    Depthdata = new ushort[DWidth * DHeight];
    ushort[] Depthloc = new ushort[DWidth * DHeight];
    depthframe.CopyFrameDataToArray(Depthdata);
    for (int i = 0; i < DWidth * DHeight; i++)
        {
          Depthloc[i] = 0x1000;
        }
        colorspacePoint = new ColorSpacePoint[DWidth * DHeight];
        depthspacePoint = new DepthSpacePoint[CWidth * CHeight];
        sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapDepthFrameToColorSpace(Depthloc, colorspacePoint);
        for (int y = 0; y < DHeight; y++)
            {
            for (int x = 0; x < DWidth; x++)
                {
                if (depthshft != 0)
                   {
                    Depthdata[y * DWidth + x] = (ushort)((Depthdata[y * DWidth + x]) << depthshft);
                   }

                 }
             }
         depth.CopyPixelData(Depthdata);
 }
WbDepth.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, DWidth, DHeight), Depthdata, strideDep, 0);
ImageDepth.Source = WbDepth;
if (depth != null && DepthWriter.FileName != null) Cv.WriteFrame(DepthWriter, depth);
Cv.ReleaseVideoWriter(DepthWriter);
if (CheckBox_saveD.IsChecked == true)
DepthWriter = new CvVideoWriter(string.Format("{1}\\Scene{0}_DepthRecord.avi", scene, TextBlock_saveloca.Text.ToString()), FourCC.Default, 30.0f, new CvSize(512, 424));
CheckBox_saveD.IsEnabled = false;
if (CheckBox_saveD.IsChecked == true) Cv.ReleaseVideoWriter(DepthWriter);
```

Thank you

Comment: Convert it to gray scale: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html. Chances are though that if the image appears gray anyways, then each channel has the same values and you'd actually be better off just dropping the other two channels.

Comment: convert 3 channel depth image to gray scale image changes the depth values ?

Comment: Not if the values for each element are the same across each channel. If they are different, then you can't do this. My guess though is whatever function you used to load your image in Matlab converts to 3 channels by default (like `imshow` does for example). In that case converting to grey-scale wont change the values

Comment: Each element are not same across each channel...then any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Then you need to post the code of how you captured your data and loaded it into matlab

Comment: how can post my full code? can I share my dropbox folder with you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80101/discussion-between-frq-khan-and-dan).

Comment: No, you can extract the relevant code snippets, and then *EDIT YOUR QUESTION* and add them there

Comment: I have added all the lines of code that is related to the depth.
what I found so far is, during the video writer the codec is not 16 bit which make 3 channel.. I am not its correct or not

Answer (score 1):

Everyone so far is advising you to convert the (supposedly) color image to grayscale. **I don't think you should do this**.
The kinect gives you a "1 channel" image of depth values. If you have a color (3 channel) depth map, then something is wrong. Converting to gray scale will then make you **lose depth information**.

Instead, try to figure out why your image is loaded as gray scale in the first place. What is the source? Is the conversion maybe done by Matlab when reading the image? Can you then give it some flag to tell it not to?

Comment: You mean that the recorded depth video in 3 channel is not correct?

Comment: It's hard to know exactly if you don't specify the way you record. But no, a depth map with three channels makes no sense.

Comment: Here is the sample of recording depth stream [link](http://pterneas.com/2014/02/20/kinect-for-windows-version-2-color-depth-and-infrared-streams/) it is exactly similar to the way I recorded

Comment: And as you can see in the `ImageSource::ToBitmap(DepthFrame frame)` method, the single depth value is converted to a RGB-triplet. That code is quite weird since it takes a `ushort` depth value and converts it to 3 `byte` values. Thereby most likely destroying the depth data.

Comment: Simple: strip out the part that converts to RGB and save the original depth data.

Comment: here is my [code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzf3ahwpvl8lerd/Capture.PNG?dl=0), can you please point out exactly what I should change?

Comment: That code doesn't seem to do anything with depth. And it's not saving the depth to an image to be opened in Matlab either. Also please use something like pastebin to share code snippets.

Comment: Actually the full project is record the depth video streams. The above part is just to take a depth frame which is later as `if (depth != null && DepthWriter.FileName != null) Cv.WriteFrame(DepthWriter, depth);` > after video is saved I used that video in the MATLAB to extract frames

Comment: Ovren, I have found that the error was because of the saving video codec. As I tried to save the only image, then it is 1 channel depth image.. Can you suggest me  how can I solve this codec problem?